# Find an attribute on a parent method in a deep async call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am looking for a way to "add some context" to my methods for debugging purposes. Even though using [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) works fine with sync code, when going async, things naturally stop working. I fully understand why but I can't find a good way to solve this.

```
[Scope("method 1")]
private async Task Method1()
{
    // ... other awaited calls
    await DoWork();
}

[Scope("method 2")]
private async Task Method2()
{
    // ... other awaited calls
    await DoWork();
}

private async Task DoWork()
{
    // Get ScopeAttribute from parent method
    var description = new StackTrace()
      .GetFrames()
      ?.SelectMany(f => f.GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ScopeAttribute), false))
      .Cast<ScopeAttribute>()
      .FirstOrDefault()?.Description;
}
```

How to get to `ScopeAttribute` decorated on parent methods? In a sync world the above would just work. In an async world, the stack trace is lost. Any ideas?

The solution does not necessarily have to involve using attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your use-case correctly, what you're looking for is `AsyncLocal`:

```
private static AsyncLocal<string> _scope = new AsyncLocal<string>();

private async Task Method1()
{
    _scope.Value = "method 1";

    // ... other awaited calls
    await DoWork();
}

private async Task Method2()
{
    _scope.Value = "method 2";

    // ... other awaited calls
    await DoWork();
}

private async Task DoWork()
{
    Console.WriteLine(_scope.Value);
}
```

Comment: Darn it if it's that simple! :) Yes, I think you understand what I want perfectly. Let me try your solution. I am having high hopes.

Comment: Just wondering... what happens if I make `_scope` static? Will it ruin my day?

Comment: @wpfwannabe it will work the exact same way, so it's probably a good idea